# Thymio-II Webots Python simulator

Tags: webots

I am trying to program Thymio-II using Python in Webots simulator. I have not understood how to access and control LEDs on Thymio-II. Are there any Python controller code examples for Thymio-II which would illustrate use of LEDs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [C example](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/released/projects/robots/mobsya/thymio/controllers/thymio2_demo/thymio2_demo.c) and you will understand how to access all the LEDs of the Thymio-II in Python:

```py
led = robot.getLED('leds.circle.led0')  # get a reference to one of the LEDs of the robot
let.set(32)  # turn on the LED
```

Comment: Thank you Olivier, this was useful!